# python multiprocessing error about apply_async

Tags: python, multiprocessing

This is my code segment :

```
def getEnergyTerm(size , elements , elementSize , elementType , elementLine , elementGroup , imageElement , Dis , background):
    pdb.set_trace()
    functionList = [alignCalc , whiteSpace , getBalanceGravityCenter , spread , dist , margin , textSize , textVar , minTextSize , textContrast , textOverlap , graphicTextOverlap , graphicBoundary ,  groupSizeVar , groupDistMean]
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool()

    result = []
    #whiteSpace(size , elements , elementSize , elementType , elementLine , elementGroup , imageElement , background)
    #pool.apply_async(whiteSpace , args = (size , elements , elementSize , elementType , elementLine , elementGroup , imageElement , background))
    for func in functionList:
        result.append(pool.apply_async(func , args = (size , elements , elementSize , elementType , elementLine , elementGroup , imageElement , background)))

    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    print result
    energy = {k:v for item in result for k , v in item.get().items()}
    return energy
```

the function in functionList such as this :

```
def whiteSpace(size , elements , elementSize , elementType , elementLine , elementGroup , imageElement , background):
    #pdb.set_trace()
    sum = size[0] * size[1]
    for item in range(len(elements)):
        sum -= elementSize[item][0] * elementSize[item][1]

    sum = sum * 1.0 / (size[0] * size[1])

    E_white_space =  -1.0 * sigmod(sum , alpha)
    res = {}
    res['whiteSpace'] = E_white_space
    return res
```

I use the pdb to debug my code and the error is happen , this is error info:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 114, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 102, in worker
    task = get()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 376, in get
    return recv()
TypeError: __new__() takes exactly 4 arguments (2 given)
```

I just want use the python multiprocessing to optimize the speed of my code , so I have no knowledge about multiprocessing and I can't understand this error, Can someone help me ?

thanks a lot

Comment: oh sorry , the error happened in `pool.apply_async(fund , args = (size , ....))`

Comment: If you have understood the error then you can set it as an answer to your own question

Comment: @AlexanderMorley actually when I search the way to use multiprocessing , the most people give the demo like this , but there are some error for my code, this is strange.

Answer (score 0):

Oh , I got it , the reason is my parameter in apply_async()'s args , may be this args is not support a object parameter. Let me detail it:
In my code , `background = Image.open('background')` , and if I remove it from `pool.apply_async(func , args = (size , elements , elementSize , elementType , elementLine , elementGroup , imageElement , background))` , It's work!

But when I tried this :
    import multiprocessing
    from PIL import Image

```
def testFunc(y , x , calcY, list , str , img):
    a = [i*i for i in x]
    #b = [i+i for i in y]
    b = y[0]
    c = [i+i for i in list]
    res = {}
    res['a'] = a
    res['b'] = b
    res['c'] = c
    res['str'] = str
    img.paste(0 , (100 , 100 , 100 , 100))
    res['img'] = img

    return res



if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = multiprocessing.Pool()
    img = Image.new('RGBA' , (800 , 600))
    res = p.apply_async(testFunc , args = ((2 , 3) , [2 , 3 , 4] , False , [6 , 7 , 8 , 9] , 'hello world' , img))
    print res.get()
```

It's actually work , so what's the reason about this situation ? Despite solving my question , I still can't understand what happened

Comment: another question is that：Is the multiprocessing Pool really can speed the program？I just test my code , It's actually saving 5 seconds , and On a 4 core cpu machine and on a 8 core cpu machine , the code spend same time! why about this situation!